# WPF Data Binding Validation and accompanying Data Triggers either results in a Stack Overflow Exception, or has no effect whatsoever

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, stack-overflow

I had what seems to be a fairly simple `ValidationRule` - I'm trying to validate that a particular date isn't in the future. Here's an example of code to illustrate the problem:

```
public class DateNotInTheFutureValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            var date = (DateTime)value;

            // StackOverflowException here
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            ValidationResult validationResult = null;

            if (date > now)
            {
                validationResult = new ValidationResult(false, "Cannot be in the future");
            }
            else
            {
                validationResult = ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            }

            return validationResult;
        }
    }
```

For the record, yes, I do realize that most of this can be reduced to a single expression using ternary form, but this was more helpful to illustrate the problem.

I apply it to a `DatePicker` like this:

```
<DatePicker Name="startDatePicker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="SelectedDate">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationRules:DateNotInTheFutureValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
    </DatePicker>
```

I also have the following style to handle the case when a rule is violated:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The weird thing: when I select a date in the future in the `DatePicker`, this works as expected - it runs without exception and returns the proper `ValidationResult` indicating that this is incorrect. However, the triggers don't work - I just get the following error message:

> Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'ValidationError') from '(Validation.Errors)' (type 'ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1'). BindingExpression:Path=(0)[0].ErrorContent; DataItem='DatePicker' (Name='startDatePicker'); target element is 'DatePicker' (Name='startDatePicker'); target property is 'ToolTip' (type 'Object') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index'

The new style elements aren't applied, even if I hardcode the setter for ToolTip to some text value instead of doing data binding. However, this code is taken almost directly from the documentation; also the posts I've read on this error seem to indicate that this error should only occur when you *don't* have validation errors, not when you *do*. Why is this happening?

If I remove the line setting the `ToolTip`, I don't get the error anymore, but none of the other setters have any effect whatever - the `DatePicker` looks exactly the way that it did before.

However, if I set the `DatePicker` to a date in the past, I get a Stack Overflow Exception when I try to call `DateTime.Now`.

Ordinarily, a Stack Overflow Exception would indicate some kind of infinite recursion - in fact, when I set a breakpoint on this line, it *does*, in fact, get hit repeatedly, so it appears that this is exactly what's happening.

That being said, why is this happening? How could calling `DateTime.Now` possibly result in a recursive call to the Validate method? And why does it only do that when I'm passing in a date in the past?

Comment: Why are you binding the `SelectedDate` property of the DatePicker to itself? (That would seem a likely cause for a stack overflow...)

Comment: @Richardissimo What should I bind to instead?

Comment: WPF is commonly done using MVVM, where the bound values are on a ViewModel.

Comment: @Richardissimo Turns out you were totally right - switching to binding to a ViewModel fixed both problems. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the SelectedDate property of the DatePicker to itself. (That would seem a likely cause for a stack overflow...)

WPF is commonly done using MVVM, where the bound values are on a ViewModel, try that.

Answer (score 2):

Below statement will trigger infinite loop, because you binding property to itself (SelectedDate)

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="SelectedDate">
```

If you have datacontext (VM) member, you can bind to it.

Otherwise, you can repurposing to existing property like 'Tag' as below to make it work

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag">
```

Hope this helps.